# Python "expected an indented block"

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
option == 1
while option != 0:
    print("MENU")
    option = input()
    print("please make a selection")
    print("1. count")
    print("0. quit")
    if option == 1:
        while option != 0:
            print("1. count up")
            print("2. count down")
            print("0. go back")
            if option == 1:
                print "please enter a number"
                for x in range(1, x, 1):
                    print(x)
                elif option == 2:
                    print "please enter a number"
                    for x in range(x, 1, 1):
                elif option == 0:
                    break
                else:
                    print("invalid command")
    elif option == 0:
        break
```

I got an error saying `expected an indented block`. I tried to check the indentation carefully, make sure all my indents use 4 spaces, etc. but I cannot find the problem.

What is wrong with the code, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you edit your post and give us the raw error message w/ line numbers please :-)

Comment: best practice would be to use tab and not count or use spaces to match tabs. I came to this with the same problem - the fix for me was that I had a conditional code block that was commented out except for the if/elif/else statement.  Commenting in the code even when not True cleared the error message.

Answer (score 18):

Starting with `elif option == 2:`, you indented one time too many. In a decent text editor, you should be able to highlight these lines and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to fix the issue.

Additionally, there is no statement after `for x in range(x, 1, 1):`. Insert an indented `pass` to do nothing in the `for` loop.

Also, in the first line, you wrote `option == 1`. `==` tests for equality, but you meant `=` ( a single equals sign), which *assigns* the right value to the left name, i.e.

```
option = 1
```

Comment: vim is a decent editor, but the keystrokes are `[Ctrl]-[<]` (in visual mode, add a motion beforehand in normal mode)

Comment: Thanks!  This was very helpful.  But now when I try to run my program it doesn't like **option == 1** saying **option** is undefined

Comment: @Zach You meant to write `option = 1` instead of `option == 1` in the first line, didn't you? Updated the answer.

Comment: +1 This works for me .. where I am getting error, above that line, I have just applied SHIFT+TAB and that works like charm (y)

Answer (score 9):

In Python, indentation matters, e.g.:

```
if a==1:
    print("hey")

if a==2:
   print("bye")

print("all the best")
```

In this case, "all the best" will be printed if either of the two conditions executes, but if it would have been like this

```
if a==2:
   print("bye")
   print("all the best")
```

then "all the best" would be printed only if a==2.

Answer (score 6):

Your `for` loop has no loop body:

```
elif option == 2:
    print "please enter a number"
    for x in range(x, 1, 1):
elif option == 0:
```

Actually, the whole `if option == 1:` block has indentation problems. `elif option == 2:` should be at the same level as the `if` statement.

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues:

1. `elif option == 2:` and the subsequent `elif`-`else` should be aligned with the second `if option == 1`, not with the `for`.
2. The `for x in range(x, 1, 1):` is missing a body.
3. Since "option 1 (count)" requires a second input, you need to call `input()` for the second time. However, for sanity's sake I urge you to store the result in a second variable rather than repurposing `option`.
4. The comparison in the first line of your code is probably meant to be an assignment.

You'll discover more issues once you're able to run your code (you'll need a couple more `input()` calls, one of the `range()` calls will need attention etc).

Lastly, please don't use the same variable as the loop variable and as part of the initial/terminal condition, as in:

```
            for x in range(1, x, 1):
                print x
```

It may work, but it is very confusing to read. Give the loop variable a different name:

```
            for i in range(1, x, 1):
                print i
```

Answer (score 1):

Your last `for` statement is missing a body.

Python expects an indented block to follow the line with the for, or to have content after the colon.

The first style is more common, so it says it expects some indented code to follow it.  You have an `elif` at the same indent level.

Answer (score 1):

This one is wrong at least:

```
            for x in range(x, 1, 1):
        elif option == 0:
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#option = 1
#while option != 0:

print ("MENU")
print("please make a selection")
print("1. count")
print("0. quit")
option = int(input("MAKE Your Selection  "))
if option == 1:
    print("1. count up")
    print("2. count down")
    print("0. go back")
    option = int(input("MAKE Your Selection  "))
    if option == 1:
        x = int(input("please enter a number   "))
        for x in range(1, x, 1):
            print (x)

    elif option == 2:
        x = int(input("please enter a number   "))
        for x in range(x, 0, -1):
            print (x)
    elif option == 0:
        print("hi")
    else:
        print("invalid command")
else:
    print ("H!111")
```

You can try this code! It works.

Answer (score 0):

The body of the loop is indented: indentation is Python’s way of grouping statements. At the interactive prompt, you have to type a tab or space(s) for each indented line. In practice you will prepare more complicated input for Python with a text editor; all decent text editors have an auto-indent facility. When a compound statement is entered interactively, it must be followed by a blank line to indicate completion (since the parser cannot guess when you have typed the last line). Note that each line within a basic block must be indented by the same amount.

src: ##

##https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#using-python-as-a-calculator