# Command Have Error After Using If In Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x

Hi guys i have this code

```
if s == 10: 
S   ="A"    
elif s ==   11 :    
S   ="B"    
elif s ==   12 :    
S   ="C"    
elif s ==   13 :    
S   ="D"    
elif s ==   14 :    
S   ="E"    
elif s ==   15 :    
S   ="F"    
else:
S   =s
```

and i have an error  can You Help Me

S   ="A"
 ^
expected an indented block

i used an other command But Error Is Still There Can any one Help Me

Comment: "expected an indented block". You need add tab before S = "A".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python "expected an indented block"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901436/python-expected-an-indented-block)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use indentation *(spaces or tabs)(stay consistent in use)* to tell Python what's part of the if-statement and what isn't. As of now, there's nothing that could be run if the if-statement evaluates to true. Also, the `S =` are outside of those loops because of that.

```
if s == 10: 
    S   ="A"
```

This is what you most likely want.